# "Set in stone in 1979..." or "Carved in stone in 1979" at beginning of sentence?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

If I start a sentence with *"Set in stone in 1979, the government ban on so-and-so..."* or *"Carved in stone in 1979, the government ban on so-and-so...*", are both of these examples **correct in grammar**?

Also, do the two idioms have the **same meaning**?

Comment: ***set in stone*** - 
If an agreement, policy, or rule is set in stone, it is completely decided and cannot be changed. *The exact terms of the scheme have yet to be set in stone. These are just preliminary ideas and nothing is set in stone. Note: Other verbs such as **carved** or **cast** can be used instead of set. These ideas are up for discussion — they are not cast in stone.* https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+in+stone

Comment: It is very weird to **append a date** to set or carved in stone.

Comment: @Lambie I think I understand where you're coming from. Would the sentence be strange if written, "Set in stone **since** 1979, the ban on so-and-so...", having said "since" instead of "in".

Comment: Yes, that sounds better, indeed. :)

Comment: "Carved in stone" is generally used in a more literal sense than "set in stone".